# How to get more quota for creating projects for Data API v3 in YouTube?

Tags: api, youtube, limit, quota

I was making my 24 or 25 Windows App and the next message appeared:

> You have reached your account's quota limit for creating projects. To request more quota, submit this `<a href="https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase" target="_blank>request form</a>`.

So I wonder submit this to where, to whom and by which way or tool?

Could you please help me?

Comment: Which account?  Was this on a website?  If so, what site?  What was the exact error message?  Is this a question about programming, or about your Youtube account?

Comment: I have created Other projects using App Studio (appstudio.Windows.com) using the YouTube Data API v3 for 6 months in which I had no problema, but 2 days ago I tried to make another App and when I went to the You Tube developers console to obtain another Key I received the next message:

Comment: You have reached your account's quota limit for creating projects. To request more quota, submit this <ahref="https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase" target= "_blank">request form</a>.    If you would like to see the screen context you can go to http://1drv.ms/1dvObw6